# Update Report Viewer Currency Based On Region

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm trying to have my report adjust to computer's local region that generates the report. May I ask how abouts do I do that?

I tried two things.

First thing I tried

Set Computer Region Location to be UK and set the field to be an expression

```
=FormatCurrency(Fields!CurrentBalance.Value,2)
```

Second thing I tried was Set computer Region to be UK and set the thread culture

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB");
Application.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

using the above methods didn't quite work. I would like to be able to change back and fourth for testing.

Comment: Is changing back and forth for testing your goal?  If so, consider that expressions are valid for the language property of the report.  Which means that you can set it to a parameter's value, and default that value to [&Language].  Which would probably be the most efficient way to flip back and forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

On Report-Properties set in Language: `=User!Language`

That chooses the current language from the running `Thread`

**Screen**

[image: Language]